# Where Not Exists on an ID - Show results

Tags: mysql

I am working on an Online Store. My client has asked me for a list of products that arent assigned a category. I thought this would have been easy, But it appears not quite as easy as expected.

The two tables I am looking in are shop_products and shop_products_categories. They have the following setup :

**Shop Products**

- id,
- name,
- description,
- price

**Shop Products Categories**

- shop_product_id
- shop_category_id

I have tried a

```
SELECT shop_product_id 
from shop_products_categories 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT name from shop_products)
```

But that just seems to bring back all the ID's from the categories table.

Any help or a point in the right direction would be appreciated.

An SQL Fiddle of this is available [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74924/1)

The XEROX product does not have a category. Wheras the Zip Bag does.

Comment: Can you post some sample data for each table?  Are you sure that you have products without categories?  You stated that the answers return zero, that would be the case if all products had categories.

Comment: Agreed, I am just piecing together an SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Interesting, it works in the SQL Fiddle. But doesnt work in my direct SQL Database.. I have added the fiddle to the question : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74924/1

Comment: If you run `select count(*) from shop_products` and `select count(distinct shop_product_id) from shop_products_categories` are the totals different? ([demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74924/5))

Comment: Hi @bluefeet both totals are the same : 
Shop_Products : 27243
Shop_Products_Categories: 27243

Comment: That means each product is assigned a category, so you will get zero rows returned with the answers below.

Comment: @bluefeet Every product does indeed have a category. When I imported all the products, I added them to category_id 1169. I have since removed that category and Lemonstand shows its name as blank. I need to try find all products assigned to that blank, But that looks like its every product on the site :/ nightmare..

Comment: What exactly did you do? What does "I have since removed that category" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to the following which will return all products that are not in the `shop_products_categories` table:

```
select p.id, p.name, p.description, p.price
from shop_products p
where not exists (select 1
                  from shop_products_categories c
                  where p.id = shop_product_id);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50297/1)

---

It seems you still have problems and I suspect they are related to `NULL` values in the `shop_category_id` column. Try this, too:

```
select p.id, p.name, p.description, p.price
from shop_products p
where not exists (select 1
                  from shop_products_categories c
                  where p.id = shop_product_id
                    and c.shop_category_id IS NOT NULL
                 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Using where NOT EXISTS via subqueries are typically not per great for performance but does work.  A more common approach is to do a LEFT-JOIN and look for NULL (ie: doesn't exist)

```
select
      sp.id,
      sp.name,
      sp.description,
      sp.price
   from
      Shop_Products sp
         LEFT JOIN Shop_Products_Categories spc
            on sp.id = spc.shop_product_id
   where
      spc.shop_product_id is null
```

Comment: Hi @DRapp the performance issue wont be an issue, as I am just running it as a one of query for my customer. 

The query you suggested is returning 0 results.

Comment: The query is correct (and so is @bluefeet's query). If you have 0 rows returned, you have 0 products that are not assigned to a category.

Comment: I agree with what your saying @ypercube but my admin login is showing their are products not assigned.

Answer (score 1):

Use this query it may help you

```
SELECT * FROM shop_products WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT shop_product_id FROM shop_products_categories);
```

Comment: @StuBlackett have you got solution for this??

Comment: unfortunatley not. All answers are returning 0 results.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,i am not sure:

```
Select id from shopproducts where not exist (select s.id from shopproduct as s inner    
joinshop_products_categories)
```

meaning that ids from productshop that not exist in join of two table